# how to keep the precision while floating a string in python?

Tags: python, floating-point

The built-in `float` can't keep the precison(eg.float('123.45678' = 123.45677999999999), I rewrite it, but also meet the same problem. My question is as the title.

```
a_int = lambda s : sum(((ord(s[j])-48)*(10**(len(s)-j-1)) for j in range(len(s))))

def a_float(s):
    l = s.split(".")
    return a_int(l[0]+l[1]) / 10.0**len(l[1])

>>> s = "11223.512512"
>>> a_float(s)
11223.512511999999
```

Comment: You can't. That's the nature of floating point values. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: I strongly recommend *not* rewriting `float`: getting fast and correct decimal-to-binary conversions is *hard*!

Answer (score 3):

Floating point values *are not precise*. They are binary fraction approximations instead; e.g. the computer adds up 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8, etc. (but picking those fractions based on your actual value), adding those up to approximate the decimal value. A `float` value can simply not represent the value `11223.512512` precisely. This is the price of hardware-acceleration support; `float` operations are extremely fast, and usually precise *enough*.

Don't use `float` values if precision is important; use the [`decimal.Decimal()` type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) instead. Or decide on how many digits you want to represent when printing, and format your floating point values with `format()`:

```
print format(a_float(s), '.6f')
```

I recommend you read the [*Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations* chapter](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) of the Python tutorial for more details.

Comment: It is not so much a matter of precision than of exact representation of decimal fractions. A decimal type has the same problem representing one third.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: The OP is not talking about fractions here though.